# Apply Excel Formula with openpyxl

Tags: python, openpyxl

I would like to update values in empty cells of a column with a formula:

```
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook("filename.xlsx")
ws = wb.worksheets[0]

start_row = 30
formula = "=((N7-N6)*90,5%)*" + str(100) + "%" 

for cell in ws["C:C"]:
    try:
        if cell.row <= start_row-1:

            ws["C" + str(cell.row)] = formula
```

However, as soon as I try to open the .xlsx file (exported as wb.save("filename_1.xlsx")) with Excel I get an error regarding invalid data.

Comment: See https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html#using-formulae

Answer (score 0):

Simply put, the formula you’re trying to insert is not a valid formula.

The effective formula you’re entering is `=((N7-N6)*90,5%)*100%`. It’s the part after the multiplication with 90 that’s incorrect.

Try to enter the formula first right into the spreadsheet software. Once you have a working formula, copy it over and tweak it in your Python script. Good luck!